# Override method in multi inherite C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I see this problem in C++.

```
class A{
 public:
   char* getName(){ return "A";}
   void showData(){
     cout<<"A";
   }
};

class B:public A{
public:
  void showData(){
    A::showData();
    cout<<"B";
  }
};

class C:public A{
public:
 void ShowData(){
   A::showData();
   cout<<"C";
 }
};

class D:public B,public C{
 public:
  void showData(){
    B::showData();
    C::showData();
    cout<<"D"; 
  }   
};
```

Problem1:
    D* d=new D();
    d->showData(); // I want it prints "ABCD" but it prints "ABACD"

Problem2:

cout<<  d->getName();   // it shows error:  ambiguous access of 'getName'

Can you help me solve 2 problems?
Thanks.

Comment: this isn't valid C++ code. Please post compilable code. But if you follow the code, you should see why it prints the output `ABACD`

Comment: `cout<getName` isn't valid in your Problem2 either. Problem1 prints exactly what it is supposed to: D calls B, which calls A, which prints **A**. then B prints **B**, then D calls C which calls A, which prints **A**, then C prints **C**, then D prints **D**. Result: **ABACD**, exactly what you asked it to do.

Comment: d call getName method but D inherite from B and C, and both B and C are contain getName How to solve this problem?

Comment: @user1956702 I see that you have not accepted answers to any of your questions. If an answer helps you, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the little check-mark next to it. This helps contributors to more easily find unanswered questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem 2 is happening because your class D contains two copies of the base class A. When you call `d->getName()`, the compiler does not know which one to pick up. To fix this, use [`virtual inheritance`](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html).

Simply put, derive your class `A` *virtually* in both classes `B` and `C`:

```
class A { ... }

class B : public virtual A { ... }

class C : public virtual A { ... }

class D : public B, public C { ... }
```

This guarantees a single embedded copy of class A in class D and will solve the ambiguous access error.

As for problem 1, virtual inheritance will be a good start, but you will need to find some way to rework your logic so that `A::getName()` is not called twice when you call `D::getName()`.